# All column names not listed by df.columns

Tags: pandas

I wanted to perform groupby and agg fucntion on my dataframe, so i performed the below code

```
basic_df = df.groupby(['S2PName','S2PName-Category'], sort=False)['S2PGTotal'].agg([('totSale','sum'), ('count','size')])

basic_df.head(2)
```

My O/P:

```
                              totSale               count
S2PName     S2PName-Category        
IDLY         Food                 598771.47             19749
DOSA          Food                567431.03             14611
```

Now I try to print the columns using `basic_df.columns`

My O/P:

```
Index(['totSale', 'count'], dtype='object')
```

Why are the other two columns "S2pname and S2PName-category" not being displayed. What do I need to do to display them as well?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `as_index=False`, or `reset_index()` at the end

```
basic_df = df.groupby(['S2PName','S2PName-Category'], sort=False,as_index=False)['S2PGTotal'].agg([('totSale','sum'), ('count','size')])

#basic_df = df.groupby(['S2PName','S2PName-Category'], sort=False)['S2PGTotal'].agg([('totSale','sum'), ('count','size')]).reset_index()
```

Comment: I get an attribute error, when I add as_index=False . But rest_index() works. Is there  any explanation  why pandas behaves so ?

Comment: @RageshKr sometime the as_index=False will not work when you agg more than two , reset_index usually works fine ~

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the answer !